# Is it possible to tail call optimize a grouping function in f# using sequences?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Here is my attempt which is NOT tail call optimized because I need to dispose the enumerator:

```
let Group func seed (items : seq<'t>) = 
    let rec some (i : IEnumerator<'t>) state = seq {
        try
            if i.MoveNext()
            then
                let newstate, iscomplete = func (i.Current) state
                if iscomplete
                then 
                    yield newstate
                    yield! some i newstate
            else
                yield state
        finally
            i.Dispose() }

    some (items.GetEnumerator ()) seed
```

And here is example usage:

```
let buffer maxBufferSize items =
    Group (fun item state ->
        let newstate = [ item ] |> List.append state
        if newstate.Length >= maxBufferSize
        then (newstate, true)
        else (newstate, false)) List.empty items
```

If I can avoid using the enumerator (i.e. `Seq.head AND Seq.tail`) I could make it work but without `Seq.tail` I am at a loss. I am really hoping to make this work with generic sequences..

And FYI I know this code won't work in its current state because I would end up disposing the enumerator multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the `try .. finally` block from the inner `some` function (where it is entered during every iteration) to the main function. Then the inner recursive function `some` becomes tail-recursive:

```
let Group func seed (items : seq<'t>) =  
    // The handling of exceptions is done by the caller, 
    // so 'some' does not need to handle exceptions...
    let rec some (i : IEnumerator<'t>) state = seq { 
        if i.MoveNext() 
        then 
            let newstate, iscomplete = func (i.Current) state 
            if iscomplete then  
                yield newstate 
                // Recursive call in tail-call position
                yield! some i newstate 
        else 
            yield state }

    // Return a sequence that wraps the obtains the IEnumerator
    // and guarantees that it gets disposed if 'some' fails
    seq {
      let i = items.GetEnumerator ()
      try 
          // This is still not-tail recursive
          yield! some i seed 
      finally
          i.Dispose() }
```

Or even better, you can implement the sequence that is returned from `Group` using the `use` construct:

```
    seq {
        use i = items.GetEnumerator ()
        // This is still not-tail recursive
        yield! some i seed }
```

Actually, I think this is more correct than your original code, because it calls the `Dispose` method only once. In your version, it would be called once for every time the execution enters `some` (which would depend on the number of elements processed before an exception happens).

Comment: That was my first implementation but I thought i would be disposed when it goes out of scope and I thought it would go out of scope after the yield!. Since the sequence was lazy then the enumerator would end up disposed before the sequence gets enumerated... Am I crazy?

Comment: @Brad The trick is to use the `use` keyword _inside_ the `seq { .. }` block. Then the F# compiler generates code that disposes the resource after the entire sequence is enumerated. This would be problem only if `use` was inside the body of `Group`, but not inside `seq { .. }` that later calls `some` using `yield!`. Hope this makes sense!